# Should I disable CPU fan error message and how?

Tags: cpu, bios, computer-building, fan

I have just completed my first "build" consisting of:

- [ASUS P8Z77-V-Deluxe](http://www.asus.com/Motherboard/P8Z77V_DELUXE/) motherboard,
- [Intel i7-3770](http://ark.intel.com/products/65719/) processor,
- [Coolermaster Hyper 212 EVO](http://www.coolermaster-usa.com/product.php?product_id=3053) CPU cooler.

Each time I boot the computer, the following error message is displayed:

> CPU fan error. Press F for settings

The CPU fan speed varies around 500 RPM and the temperature starts at 70°F (20°C) and goes up to 80°F (27°C).

I know how to get into the bios. When I press DEL I get the CPU fan error message. Then I press F1 and I get into the BIOS where I set the boot priority. Then I press EXIT, SAVE CHANGES ans RESET.
But it does not boot. I keep getting back to "PRESS DEL..., etc.
What modification(s) should I make to disable or bypass this alert and is it safe to do so?

Comment: Electrical tape works for the "check engine" light on my car.

Answer (score 10):

I was getting same error message on my Maximus V Gene with Cooler Master 212 Plus CPU Cooler.

This error message is diplayed when CPU fan RPM is below specified limit. For my motherboard, specified low limit was 600 RMP and CM 212 Plus Cooler fan was running at 500-550RPM.

If CPU temperature is ok, then you need not to worry. If you want to turn of this error message, then goto:

**BIOS -> Monitor -> Fan Speed Monitor**

Here, you can see all fans connected to your system are being monitored. You now need to select **CPU fan**. Two options will popup - Monitor and Ignore. Select **Ignore**.

Error message will not be shown thereafter.

Comment: does not work for me

Comment: @IARI Can you specify the motherboard name and model that you are using?

Comment: Maximus VIII Ranger - are there multiple models of that?

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the CPU fan is connected to the CPU fan header on your motherboard. The manual should have a layout of the various fan connectors. I'm guessing you have the CPU fan plugged into a case header. This would allow the CPU fan to work but the motherboard would report an error.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you should know **before** you commence a build, and how to enter the BIOS is one of them. You should also have access, whether online or offline, to the specific motherboard's user manual.

You can go here to find the manual for the ASUS P8Z77-V-Deluxe motherboard:
http://www.asus.com/Motherboard/P8Z77V_DELUXE/#support_Download

According to the user manual, in order to enter the BIOS, you hold down the DEL key on the keyboard during POST. I would recommend you take the initiative to read the manual now and learn how to disable the fan error settings. Do you actually have the 212 Evo's power cable connected to the motherboard's main CPU fan header? If not, that's likely why you're getting an error. It's no big deal. Just disable the header in the BIOS (read the manual first).

Answer (score -2):

Solved for my issue.
I kept getting this error when i would open the DELL and start up:
The fan on the power supply worked 
The fan on the motherboard/processor worked
The fan in front of the Hard drive was the non-responsive one.(this fan was tested on another PC and worked just fine)

-Disconnect the non-working fan(just the cable)
-When the error screen pops up select F2.  Clear out the Event log errors (in the bios).
-While the PR is running connect the fan back into the motherboard(if the fan turns on right after you do it, then chances are your problem will be solved)

Restart the PC and see if the error is fixed. 
PS:  I tried to clear the event log by itself prior to unplugging and re plugging in the fan and that did not work

Comment: Having a CPU fan spinning slowly (question indicated 500 RPM) and ready to immediately step up if the temperature increases is far far better than running the system with the cable disconnected.  Passive cooling is possible, but you want a heatsink designed for that, and especially do not want unpowered fan blades sitting in the way of airflow.